# there is an error with enable disable textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have written a simple jquery to enable `textboxes` on the click of  button but the when i click , for a second the textbox enables and then goes to disabled state again

code is :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Profile Page</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script>
         $(function(){
             $("#edit").click(function () {
               $('*').prop('disabled',false);
                 }); 
            });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>User Profile</h1></center><br><br>

<form action="" method="post">
<table>
 <tr>  
     <td>  User ID </td>  <td> <input type="text" name="uid" disabled> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
 <td>First Name </td>  <td><input type="text" name="fname" disabled> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
 <td>  Last Name </td>  <td><input type="text" name="lname" disabled> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
     <td>  Email </td>  <td><input type="text" name="email" disabled> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
 <td>  Country </td>  <td><input type="text" name="country" disabled> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>  <input type="Submit" value="Edit" id="edit">  </td> 
     <td>  <input type="Submit" value="Update" onclick="update()">  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

i have also added the json jar in the libraries

Comment: ok got your point ..thnks a lot man

Comment: you should prevent the default behavior to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler doesn't cancel the default behaviour of the button, which is to submit the form. The form's action is blank, so a submit basically reloads the page.

You could change the button so that it isn't a submit button (and thus has no default behaviour):

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit">
```

Or you could change your JS to cancel the default behaviour:

```
 $("#edit").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // <-- add this, and add the 'e' argument to the function
   $('*').prop('disabled',false);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's becuase you're using `<input type='submit'...`

please use `<input type='button'....` you will be able to enable all input boxes.

With `type=submit` the form gets submitted and the page reloaded again, so the input box's property "disabled" is applied again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `please use <input type='button'.... you will be able to enable all input boxes.` that's bad advice. You should always use `type="submit"` (for accessibility reasons) and hook to the `submit()` event.